# How to fix importerror or Pythonanywhere deployment with Python upgrade?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am using Python 3.8 on my mac and developing an app for more then two years. I am hosting this app on PythonAnywhere because I'm using Sqlite3.

Now PA sent me an email that I need to upgrade the system image from Python 3.8 to 3.10. I never done this before so I'm registered a free account and deployed the exactly same app to test the process.

I made a new project, virtualenv and installed Python 3.10 and Django 5.0 (tried 3.1 too - this is the version on my Mac). I did all the setting ans setted the wsgi too like many times before in other projects.

When I installed all the apps and try to run the site I get this very long error traceback:

```
2023-12-20 18:37:37,746: Error running WSGI application
2023-12-20 18:37:38,100: ImportError: cannot import name 'SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin' from 'django.contrib.auth.views' (/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,100:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
2023-12-20 18:37:38,100:     response = self.get_response(request)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,101: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,101:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
2023-12-20 18:37:38,101:     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,101: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,101:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner
2023-12-20 18:37:38,102:     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,102: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,102:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
2023-12-20 18:37:38,102:     response = handle_uncaught_exception(
2023-12-20 18:37:38,102: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,103:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
2023-12-20 18:37:38,103:     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,103: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,103:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response
2023-12-20 18:37:38,103:     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
2023-12-20 18:37:38,104: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,104:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 428, in get_traceback_html
2023-12-20 18:37:38,104:     c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,104: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,104:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 411, in get_traceback_data
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105:     c["raising_view_name"] = get_caller(self.request)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 102, in get_caller
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105:     resolver_match = resolve(request.path)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,105:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106:     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 683, in resolve
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106:     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,106:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2023-12-20 18:37:38,107:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,107: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,107:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 735, in url_patterns
2023-12-20 18:37:38,107:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,107: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,111:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2023-12-20 18:37:38,111:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,111: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,111:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 728, in urlconf_module
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/MPSA/firm/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113:     from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,113:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:38,114:     from two_factor.views import (
2023-12-20 18:37:38,114: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,114:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:38,114:     from .core import (
2023-12-20 18:37:38,115: 
2023-12-20 18:37:38,115:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/views/core.py", line 15, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:38,115:     from django.contrib.auth.views import SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin
2023-12-20 18:37:48,218: Error running WSGI application
2023-12-20 18:37:48,506: ImportError: cannot import name 'SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin' from 'django.contrib.auth.views' (/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507:     response = self.get_response(request)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507:     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,507:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 57, in inner
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 140, in response_for_exception
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:     response = handle_uncaught_exception(
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,508:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509:     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 428, in get_traceback_html
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509:     c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 411, in get_traceback_data
2023-12-20 18:37:48,509:     c["raising_view_name"] = get_caller(self.request)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 102, in get_caller
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510:     resolver_match = resolve(request.path)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 24, in resolve
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510:     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,510: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 683, in resolve
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 735, in url_patterns
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,511: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 728, in urlconf_module
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,512:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/MPSA/firm/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:     from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:     from two_factor.views import (
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:     from .core import (
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513: 
2023-12-20 18:37:48,513:   File "/home/ruszakmikloseu/.virtualenvs/mpa-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/two_factor/views/core.py", line 15, in <module>
2023-12-20 18:37:48,514:     from django.contrib.auth.views import SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin
```

I never seen before SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin.
I don't know how to fix this. Could it be an error because of the upgraded Python 3.10 or Django 5.0?

Thank you in advance if somebody can help me out!

Comment: Do not know how to fix, but I know that Django 4.1 changed this `SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin`.  Check the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/4.1/#miscellaneous) where it states *"The undocumented django.contrib.auth.views.SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin mixin is replaced by RedirectURLMixin."*  Since this is an internal thing, perhaps you are using a deprecated method in your authentication views, forms?  Or perhaps it is the package `django-two-factor-auth` that is causing the problem?  I don't think it supports Django 5.0 yet.

Comment: You are right! It works now well with Django 4.0! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raphael's comment if found the solution. The problem was that in Django 4.1 `SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin` has been replaced with `RedirectURLMixin` and the latest version (1.3) of `django-two-factor-auth` id using the SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin.

So I downgraded to Django 4.0 and it works fine.